# How to customize the labels of an Infragistics Ultrachart?

Tags: vb.net, infragistics

I am trying to customize the series labels of the X axis of a linear ultrachart using vb.net.

I looked into the [documentation from Infragistics](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/Chart_Label_Formatting.html) and found that I could use this code:

```
UltraChart.Axis.Y.Labels.SeriesLabels.FormatString = "<Item_Label>"
```

A description of the types of labels available can be seen [here](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/Chart_Use_Predefined_and_Custom_Label_Styles.html).
However, I'm not getting the result I expected. I get **"Row#1"** and I want to get only the **"1"**.

I've tried the approach used in the first reply of [this post](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/55707.aspx) in Infragistics forums, which consists of using an hashtable with the customized labels. The code used there is the following (in C#):

```
Hashtable labelHash = new Hashtable();
labelHash.Add("CUSTOM", new MyLabelRenderer());
ultraChart1.LabelHash = labelHash;
xAxis.Labels.ItemFormatString = "<CUSTOM>";

public class MyLabelRenderer : IRenderLabel
{
    public string ToString(Hashtable context)
    {
        string label = (string)context["ITEM_LABEL"];
        int row = (int)context["DATA_ROW"];
        int col = (int)context["DATA_COLUMN"];
        //use row, col, current label's text or other info inside the context to get the axis label.
        //the string returned here will replace the current label.
        return label;
    }
}
```

This approach didn't work either.
I am using Infragistics NetAdvantage 2011.1.

Anyone has any idea how to customize these labels in order to obtain the number after "Row#"?

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to solve this task. One possible solution could be if you are using FillSceneGraph event. By this way you could get your TEXT primitives and modify it. For example:

```
 private void ultraChart1_FillSceneGraph(object sender, Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Events.FillSceneGraphEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Primitive pr in e.SceneGraph)
        {
            if (pr is Text  &&((Text)pr).labelStyle.Orientation == TextOrientation.VerticalLeftFacing )
            {
                pr.PE.Fill = Color.Red;
                ((Text)pr).SetTextString("My custom labels");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but unfortunately I'm not using FillSceneGraph at all. What I've been looking for to solve this problem is something similar to this (it doesn't have to be just one line): `UltraChart.Axis.Y.Labels.SeriesLabels.FormatString = "<Item_Label>"`, but instead of formatting, I want to be able to set the text of the label (similar to what we do when we change the text of a textbox). If you have any idea how to do this, please let me know.

Comment: @alhalama, yes, I did try what Georgi suggested. I get an exception (`InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Infragistics.UltraChart.Core.Primitives.GraphicsContext' to type 'Infragistics.UltraChart.Core.Primitives.Text'.`) when I try to run the following code: 
        `For Each pr1 In e.SceneGraph
            If (pr1 Is Text And DirectCast(pr1, Text).labelStyle.Orientation = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.TextOrientation.VerticalLeftFacing) Then
                DirectCast(pr1, Text).SetTextString(i.ToString)
            End If
        Next
        i = 1`

Comment: In VB And evaluates both sides regardless whether the first condition is true or false while in C# && only evaluates the right if the first condition is true.  Replace And with AndAlso and you will have the same behavior as C# and this should resolve your InvalidCastException.  For example: If (pr1 Is Text AndAlso DirectCast(pr1, Text).labelStyle.Orientation = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.TextOrientation.VerticalLeftFacing)

Comment: @alhalama, I've tried again using AndAlso in the If condition and I'm not longer getting the exception. However, I still don't get the result I wanted (the X axis labels still display ROW#1 instead of 1).

Comment: Can you provide the updated code that you are currently using?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I`ll try to explain more deeply about FormatString property. 
When you are using this property, you could determinate which information to be shown (for example: Items values or Data Values or Series Values). Of course there are option to use your custom FormatString. 
For example:

axisX2.Labels.ItemFormat=AxisItemLabelFormat.Custom;
axisX2.Labels.ItemFormatString ="";

In this case we have labels which represent Date on your X axis, so if you are using these two properties, you are able to determinate the Date format (for example dd/MM/yyyy  or MM/ddd/yy). In your scenario you have string values on your X axis. If you are not able to modify these strings values at lower level (for example in your database, through TableAdapters SQL query, DataSet, i.e. before to set your DataSource to our UltraChart), then you could use FillSceneGraph event and modify your Text primitives. More details about this event you could find at http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2013.1/CLR4.0/html/Chart_Modify_Scene_Graph_Using_FillSceneGraph_Event.html  If you need a sample or additional assistance, please do not hesitate to create a new forum thread in our web site - http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/
I`ll be glad to help you.